# C# Converting to date from inconsistent string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse a file where I get my dates as string like those:

```
5/18/2020 8:38:32 AM
6/8/2021 10:11:42 PM
11/24/2021 9:21:54 AM
----
```

I tried to use a `DateTime.TryParse` on my string and test the "---" case in a if statement which work but it succeed to convert only the `6/8/2021 12:41:56 PM`.
I tried to use `TryParseExact` and specify a date format but it seem that I should make a case months with one and two digits and same the days.

I guess there is something I'm not seeing or don't know.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Please add the code you are using as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are probably on a culture other than en-US which those dates are formatted in. Use IFormatProvider parameter. ie:

```
void Main()
{
    var dates = @"5/18/2020 8:38:32 AM
6/8/2021 10:11:42 PM
11/24/2021 9:21:54 AM
----";

    foreach (string s in dates.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(s, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime d))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [.Net fiddle link.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SgW0RV)

EDIT: Note that the version on .Net fiddle is slightly different because of the older C# version there.

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact details, I have to guess:

If he only can translate the 6/8 date, you may have the wrong locale settings (you have something like MM/dd/yyyy .... but this works only for the 8th of june, what you might get wrong with 6th of august)

If you use ParseExact, you can also provide a list of valid format strings.

**EDIT**

Cetins answer is correct. Additionally, the title of the post is a bit confusing, because the datetime string **IS consistent** (in the 'en-US' local settings)

Answer (score 0):

@Cetin Basoz You are right, it was indeed a culture problem. Thank you!

@nabuchodonossor You are right about the datetime string ("----" apart) being consistent. What I wanted to say was that there is no every time two digits for the days or months which would not happen if the dates were something like 05/18/2020 and 06/08/2021. Sorry, I have a hard time being precise.